# Content type of S3 key is being set as 'application/octet-stream' even after explicitly setting it to "text/plain", in python boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I have to save a certain textfile to S3 using boto. I have fetched the textfile using "requests" library. I have written the following code to save the file to S3:

```
filename = "some/textfile/fi_le.txt"
k = bucket.new_key(filename)
k.set_contents_from_string(r.raw.read())
k.content_type = 'text/plain'
print k.content_type

k = bucket.get_key(filename)
print k.content_type
```

The output is:

```
text/plain
application/octet-stream
```

What should I do to set the file's content_type to 'text/plain'?

Note: I am dealing with a lot of such files, so setting it manually in AWS console is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the content type before you call `set_contents_from_string`:

```
k = bucket.new_key(filename)
k.content_type = 'text/plain'
k.set_contents_from_string(r.raw.read())
```

The reason you have to set it before, not after, is because the `set_contents_from_string` method is what actually results in the file being written to S3 - and once it's written, changes to the local object attributes won't be reflected. So instead, you set the local attributes first, before the object is written, so they'll be written properly when you set the contents.